# Restrictions on Table Names

Tags: subsonic

Are there any restrictions on the names of tables, or issues with certain names when working with SubSonic?
I have table called 'Activity' and SubSonic doesn't seem to recognise it. When it was called 'Activities' it worked fine.

Basically I am wanting to go with singular table names as a convention (and the other conventions as detailed in the [SubSonic Conventions](http://subsonicproject.com/setup/subsonic-conventions/) blog post) and added fixPluralClassNames="false" to the web.config (because I have a table called 'Focus', which SubSonic kept naming 'Focu')

Comment: If I use SubCommander it works, perhaps an issue with the build provider?

Comment: The build provider doesn't regenerate unless you modify the timestamp on the .abp file.

Comment: Does that even apply if you are debugging with Visual Studio and build the site again?

Comment: Reboot of machine seems to fix it, as ASP.NET Temporary Files not emptied by restarted Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing files in the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder (After closing Visual Studio), or changing the .abp file seems to be a valid fix to this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, reserved words in C# are not allowed as table names. I'm not sure why Activity would be a problem though. The first thing to check when a table is not generated is that the table has a primary key.

Comment: It has a primary key, as it was previously called Activities and it worked then

Answer (score 0):

One common problem that I ran into was it would not work if my tables begin with special characters or numbers. Changing that fixed it on my end. Apart from that I did not run into any other issues.